# How Do I Replace Calculated Dates That Land on Saturday or Sunday With the Preceding Friday

Tags: sql-server, date, sql-server-2008-r2

I calculate a shipping date by subtracting the lead time from the due date. If the calculated shipping date lands on a Saturday or Sunday, I would like the calculated date to change to the preceding Friday.

When I use this WHERE statement (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803987/how-do-i-exclude-weekend-days-in-a-sql-server-query)), the records that fall on Saturday or Sunday are excluded from the results.

```
SELECT
  due_date, 
  due_date - CAST(lead_time AS NUMERIC(3,0)) AS [Latest Ship Date]
FROM order_line_table
WHERE (((DATEPART(dw, due_date - CAST(lead_time AS NUMERIC(3,0)))
  + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0,1)
```

Is there a way to default to Friday when Saturday  or Sunday is calculated? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981866/sql-replace-date-values-if-date-is-saturday-or-sunday) thread suggests a CASE in a join, but this gave me conversion error

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 27.

The server is configured so that Sunday is day 1 and Saturday is day 7.

Comment: Just checking, you want `[Latest Ship Date]` to never be a weekend day?

Comment: That is correct, @Bohemian, [Latest Ship Date] should never be a weekend day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
  due_date,
  case DATEPART(dw, [Latest Ship Date]) 
    when 1 then DATEADD(DAY, -2, [Latest Ship Date])
    when 7 then DATEADD(DAY, -1, [Latest Ship Date])
    else [Latest Ship Date]
  end as [Latest Ship Date]
from (SELECT
      due_date, 
      due_date - CAST(lead_time AS NUMERIC(3,0)) AS [Latest Ship Date]
      FROM order_line_table) x
```

Comment: The original code is using `+ @@DATEFIRST with modulo 7` and is therfore culture independant. This solution isn't...

Comment: Thank you, that worked. @Shnugo, thank you for the additional information about modulo 7. I have noted this and notified the users.